I need to know can i get a data of locale storage with php to store it to mySql
//that's php file

<?php
if (isset($_post['cree'])) {
    require('/config/connexion.php');
    if (!empty(isset($_post['email'])) && !empty(isset($_post['pwr'])) && !empty(isset($_post['number'])) && !empty(isset($_post['username']))) {
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_post['email']);
        $tel = htmlspecialchars($_post['number']);
        $nom = htmlspecialchars($_post['nom']);
        $email = password_hash($_post['email'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $test = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email=?");
        $test->execute(array($email));
        if ($test->rowCount() == 0) {
            $req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO user(email,mdp,nom,tel) VALUES(?,?,?,?) ');
            $req->execute(array($email,$mdp,$nom,$tel));
            $req->closeCursor();
            $success="You have been successfully registered";
        } else {
            $msg = "A user with email " . $email . " already exists on this platform";
        }
    } else {
        $msg = "Please fill in all fields";
    }
}
?>

I need to know can i  get a data of locale storage with php to store it to mySql. now I'm trying to retrieve data from local storage, but I can't.

What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?

Unrelated to your problem, generally avoid htmlspecialchars unless you are outputting something. Using it to sanitize input is almost always wrong.

The browser will need to send the localstorage data to PHP along with the rest of the POST data. PHP cannot retrieve it directly (because it runs on the server, not in the browser)

what do you mean by local storage . local mysql  or browser local storage

`look , i have a multi step form and it's a data of it store in localstorage and i need to my php file to store it in mysql.

(if I correctly understand your question) - Just retrieve the local storage data thru JS and put it into an input field in a submission form and then send to the PHP by POST (or use ajax to send to PHP)

@Warano as I said above, if you want php to have this information then you need to send it to php from your page. You can use javascript to do that. As Ken Lee says, either put the data into a (hidden) field in a form before it is submitted, or you could submit the form and the stored data via ajax/fetch() instead of a traditional postback

can you help me to do it?

@ADyson yess i since it but i don't know how to send it

First you need to decide what approach to take, from the two we've outlined. Then you need to do some research because probably somebody has already written examples of the same concept and published the code online.

https://www.google.com/search?q=send+localstorage+data+to+server

if (isset($_post['cree'])) { will never trigger, it's $_POST, not $_post. "now I'm trying to retrieve data from local storage" Where exactly?

@brombeer leave me either your whatshapp number or your email address and I'll send you the code.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to retrieve and modify Browsers local-Storage via PHP.
However, the whole thing can be realized in a roundabout way.
I'll show you a few examples in Javascript of how you can retrieve data and save it in local storage.
The whole thing runs mainly via ajax calls in the background.
From PHP to browser's local-storage
//Fetch data from a PHP-Script and put it in Local-Storage (with jQuery)
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/XY.php',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(response) {
            localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});


//Fetch data from a PHP-Script and put it in Local-Storage (without jQuery)
fetch('http://localhost/XY.php')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data)));


//Insert data directly in Local-Storage (with PHP&JS)
let data = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
localStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify(data));

From Local-Storage to PHP
//Send Data to a PHP-Script (with jQuery)
$(document).ready(function() {
    var data = localStorage.getItem('data');
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/XY.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            data: data
        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});

//Send Data to a PHP-Script (without jQuery)
let data = localStorage.getItem('data');
fetch('http://localhost/XY.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}).then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));


thanks. but i use it and it's not works

@Warano These JavaScript snippets will send the content of data from local storage to localhost to XY.php file, which has to read and decode the JSON payload sent by JS and do your magic. Bear in mind, that you will need to implement the PHP script which handles receiving and decoding the payload by yourself, since it is not part of this answer. Simple script which reads the payload and decodes it can bo found on this page: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-receive-json-post-with-php/
